# vs2019, sql, custom test condition not showing up in test project

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

Currently I'm writing unit tests for a SQL database project, testing stored procedures. For some tests I need a custom test condition. I wrote a custom test according to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/walkthrough-use-custom-test-condition-to-verify-stored-procedure-results?view=sql-server-ver15. With some minor adjustments it works for my VS version (2019).

When I copy the dll (with the custom test) to the correct directory, the custom test should appear in the test conditions in my solution. I verified this with a colleague and on his laptop the custom test condition does appear.
Any ideas why I do not see them?

VS2019 with ssdt. VS is just updated. All the references (seem to) have the correct version.

Comment: In my experience Visual Studio can cache incorrect test information. If I'm ever suspicious of incorrect tests results, missing tests or "extra" tests I quit VS, delete the .vs/[SolutionName]/v16/TestStore folder, reopen VS and try again. Note that this loses all of the test history but usually fixes caching issues for me.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it did not solve my problem. Although I think that the solution might be somewhat like this.....

Comment: Just re-installed Visual Studio, still the same problem

Comment: I compared my solution with the solution of my colleague (that is working correctly) and I found that I'm missing the reference to the custom test condition dll (no surprise...). Adding it manually does not solve the problem (also kind of no surprise).